# How do we create users on UEC?

Tags: configuration, uec

I have setup CLC , CC ,SC and Walrus on one machine and its running fantastic, but as admin . Can we create user on this cloud ? and if we can how?

Answer (score 6):

Users can be added by the administrator explicitly by logging into the Eucalyptus web interface at `https://<cloud-controller-ip-address>:8443/`

As an administrative user, clicking the 'Users' tab, clicking on the 'Add User' button, and filling out the same user form that a user would fill out if they applied themselves.

The user will be automatically 'approved' using this method, but their account will not be active until the user clicks the link that is sent via email similar to the above method. If you'd like to use the cli, there is a command `euca-add-user` for that. Hope that was useful